# Get MP3 ID3 meta data and song duration using AudioStreamer

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm using [Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html) to play MP3s over HTTP. I need to know the duration of the song and the ID3 tags.

Is it possible to implement this in the AudioStreamer, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From his [Docs](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html):

> Limited scope
>    One point should be
>   clarified before I continue: this
>   class is intended for streaming audio.
>   By streaming, I don't simply mean "an
>   audio file transferred over HTTP".
>   Instead, I mean a continuous HTTP
>   source without an end that continues
>   indefinitely (like a radio station,
>   not a single song).

This seems to imply that getting the duration might be tough.

Here is how to get the ID3v2 tags:

> Get metadata
>    The easiest source of
>   metadata comes from the HTTP headers.
>   Inside the
>   handleReadFromStream:eventType:
>   method, use CFReadStreamCopyProperty
>   to copy the
>   kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader
>   property from the CFReadStreamRef,
>   then you can use
>   CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields to
>   copy the header fields out of the
>   response. For many streaming audio
>   servers, the stream name is one of
>   these fields.
>
> The considerably harder source of
>   metadata are the ID3 tags. ID3v1 is
>   always at the end of the file (so is
>   useless when streaming). ID3v2 is
>   located at the start so may be more
>   accessible.
>
> I've never read the ID3 tags but I
>   suspect that if you cache the first
>   few hundred kilobytes of the file
>   somewhere as it loads, open that cache
>   with AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks and
>   then read the kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag
>   with AudioFileGetProperty you may be
>   able to read the ID3 data (if it
>   exists). Like I said though: I've
>   never actually done this so I don't
>   know for certain that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

MP3 streams are divided into 'frames' which are single units of data. Some streams do add a ID3 metadata block every few frames which you could theoretically scan for and read.

See here for more information: http://jicyshout.sourceforge.net/oreilly-article/java-streaming-mp3-pt2/java-streaming-mp3-pt2.html