# Get duration of Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer from http url?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, duration, audiostreamer

I'm using Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer to stream mp3 files from url. I need to know stream duration but I can't find how?!

I tried to use the duration property of the AudioStreamer object, but it returns 0 perhaps because the stream is from an url.

Help please!

```
audioStreamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ia701509.us.archive.org/25/items/TvQuran.com__Maher/001.mp3"]]; 

        [audioStreamer start];
```

after starting the stream i want to get its duration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550621/get-mp3-id3-meta-data-and-song-duration-using-audiostreamer?rq=1

Comment: That response doesn't answer my question!

Comment: i have given u hint its up to u????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great solution using ID3 tags and AVAsset

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL  URLWithString:@"your url here"]; 
        AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        NSLog(@"> Duration = %.2f seconds", CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration));
```

Comment: I like your solution, but AFAIK, Matt Gallagher's streamer is not intended for mp3 playback. Its designed for indefinite streaming, so the duration is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```
AVAudioPlayer * sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];
sound.delegate = self;
sound.volume = 1;
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sound.duration]);
```

try this....

Comment: I need to know the stream duration before it ends :/